# how to disable delta update in Sencha Touch app?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I'm using Sencha Architect to code my sencha touch app. after trying to manually update my app.json to change "update":"delta" to "update":"full". but each time I build the project, I found Sencha Architect appended something to "add the "update":"delta"" back. How can I disable the delta update for my sencha touch app? below is my app.json. it's very clear to see that Sencha Archite(or Sencha cmd) appended the same css config to my config and added "update":"delta".

```
"css": [
      {
         "update": "full",
         "platform": [
            "phone",
            "tablet",
            "desktop"
         ],
         "theme": "Default",
         "path": "resources/css/sencha-touch-b7bf9d92-8863-494c-b8c7-7c423a420d33.css"
      },
      {
         "update": "delta",
         "platform": [
            "phone",
            "tablet",
            "desktop"
         ],
         "theme": "Default",
         "path": "resources/css/sencha-touch-b7bf9d92-8863-494c-b8c7-7c423a420d33.css"
      }
   ],
```

my .sencha/app/sencha.cfg file content
    app.name=MyMusicBox

```
app.framework=touch

app.classpath=${app.dir}/app.js,${app.dir}/app

# this property specifies a comma separated list of paths containing
# resources to copy to the build directory
app.resource.paths=

app.build.dir=${workspace.build.dir}/${app.name}

app.framework.version=2.4.0.487
app.cmd.version=5.0.3.324
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove **"update":"full"** from app.json.